# Using classes vs ids for multiple li elements example 20 with knockout and jQuery, performance and mantainability which is better?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

```
<ul class="sellerDetails sellerdetailsData " data-bind="attr: { id: 'sellerdetailsData-' + $index()}">
 <li><span class="buyerprocess-sprite seller-name"></span>
    <p class="leftfloat">
        <span data-bind="attr: { id: 'seller-Person' + $index()}" class="seller-Person">
        </span>
        <br />
        <span data-bind="attr: { id: 'seller-Name' + $index()}" class="seller-Name font13 text-light-grey">
        </span>
    </p>
 </li>
 <li><span class="buyerprocess-sprite seller-masking-no"></span>
    <p class="leftfloat">
        <span data-bind="attr: { id: 'seller-Contact' + $index()}" class="seller-Contact">
        </span>
    </p>
 </li>
 <li><span class="buyerprocess-sprite seller-email"></span>
    <p class="leftfloat">
        <span data-bind="attr: { id: 'seller-Email' + $index()}" class="seller-Email"></span>
    </p>
 </li>
 <li><span class="buyerprocess-sprite seller-address"></span>
    <p class="leftfloat">
        <span data-bind="attr: { id: 'seller-Address' + $index()}" class="seller-Address">
        </span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="font10 text-light-grey margin-left10">Your contact details have been shared
            with the seller</span></p>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**I have few queries regarding this html structure:**

- We are giving IDs to every li elements. We have 20 such li element. I got review from someone that since IDs are stored globally, this approach would create too many IDs which would further hamper the ID lookup.
- If we don't use IDs at each element level of every li and instead access by classes, its working fine but i feel it would be slower.

Example if i click on span with ['seller-Person' + $index()] and I have to access 'seller-Name' + $index(), we have two option:

- $('#seller-Name' + $(this).attr('id'))
- OR $(this).parents(.buyerprocess-sprite).find('.seller-Name')

I feel first one is more clear, should be fast.

How do we decide which approach is better?

Comment: I don't think it make slower if you use class instead of id.

Comment: By class is almost always easier to code and maintain. Performance shouldn't be a problem, but even if id was slower as mentioned in your review 20 ids is nothing.

Comment: i doubt you need any, just give the LI a number and work from there...

Comment: If you were using Knockout properly, you would not need to use jQuery selectors to handle events. At all.

Comment: I agree. I should have done all this binding through knockout then i would have to place binding at html and so such access would be needed. Thanks for the right direction. I would work on that.

But its existing code, what do you suggest for now - placing ids or accessing by classes. Its a production website with many users everyday.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, you can access all those individual li elements via a css reference. This means you don't need to use IDs at all.

Here's an example:

```js
$("li:nth-child(2)").text("updated");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't want anything like this li:nth-child, since it would traverse down to that child.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as jQuery, look this test for jquery traversal performance :

jQuery ID
$("#foo");
327,475 ops/sec
±1.93%

```
fastest
```

jQuery Class $(".bar"); 137,657 ops/sec
±1.60%

```
58% slower
```

Run test [here](https://jsperf.com/id-vs-class-vs-tag-selectors/2)

Comment: And using individual ids is likely to make the code longer and messier, so that's a performance loss in terms of development effort, and download speed.

Comment: You are both correct. 

However, I just based it in the fact that he is using Knockout.js for attribute binding, meaning download speed and development effort will not be an issue, because he's not gonna type it one by one anyway, the library will do it for him. 

So the remaining factor here is the **DOM Tree traversal**, which was explained in the above test that accessing the DOM by ID is much faster than looking up via classes.

But as explained by other comments above, 20 Li's is not a very big deal.

Comment: For me, it makes easy to refer everything with id- like contact-0, contact-1....contact-20. Yeah it may make html bit longer but i think its more readable than .find(.contact)